# Pagination link not active

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, wagtail

I'm trying to build a site with Python using Wagtail for CMS. Right now, I am creating a pagination that can go to other pages. It's clearly visible, but the link to next is not active. I feel as though the code is right, but for it not to work, something is visibly off.

[image: Blog Page]

[image: Model.py]

[image: Blog_Page.html]

Comment: Please post the codes snippets as codes instead of images, it's hard to follow like this, also for pagination you can use Django pagination easily enough with somw anchor tags

Answer (score 0):

Please post the codes snippets as codes instead of images, it's hard to follow like this, also you didn't post anything about that tag you're using maybe it's doing something wrong, and the easiest way is to make the `herf` in your templates something like this:

```
<a href="?page={{posts.next_page_number}}"></a>
```

so no need to call some kind of a tag or function to do so, if this also didn't work then make sure that it's not a front-end issue and that something is overlapping with the links making them un-reachable to click on